# Test whether $\Bbb Z$ is a $\Bbb Z_2$ module or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

How I can prove that  $\Bbb Z$ is NOT a $\Bbb Z/\langle2\rangle$ module under $\bar x.m=xm$ ?

I've seen that all the properties of module hold good. I'm unable to realize where it breaks at least one property of module ?

Can I get any hint for this ?

Comment: I think you mean to show that $\Bbb Z$ is not a $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ module.  Because $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$  is a $\Bbb Z$ module.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Sorry..!! You are right..I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $2=1+1=\overline1.1+\overline1.1=\bigl(\overline1+\overline1\bigr).1\neq\overline0.1=0$